# Excel date issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1930,1,3),NOW()-1)` in a cell to give me a random date. I have the format of the cell set to a date so the random number looks like a date. For example `38562` looks like `7/29/2005`. So far so good, however when I use the value in another formula is shows `38562` not `7/29/2005`...

So `=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO random.#persons(birth_date) VALUES ('",L1,"');")` fails as the birth_date isn't in a date format. How can I convert an number into a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `=TEXT(Date_Number, "mm/dd/yyyy")` ([function reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx)).